# How can I Read and Write Images and Text to my Firebase Real time Database

Tags: java, android, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to post picture files as a string and a title as a string.
Ive successfully was able to write to the database a title and image string but not sure how to get it to show the image file in my recyclerview

```
public class FireBaseReadWrite {

private static final String TAG = "FirebaseReadWrite";
// Firebase instance variables

DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference listRef = mRootRef.child("post");



// When a user go offline this code will keep there saved data on the device
// FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

    public FireBaseReadWrite writeFirebase(String title,String imageURL){
        Post post = new Post(title,imageURL);

        mRootRef.child("posts").setValue(post);

        return null;
    }


public void readFirebase(){
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            Log.w(TAG, String.valueOf(post));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // ...
        }
    };
```

//    mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
    }

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use Picasso library http://square.github.io/picasso/
for image loading.

lets suppose you got the Image url from firebase database i.e https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg

```
String img_url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg";
```

use library to load it into your imageView (placed into your recyclerView) like

```
Picasso.with(context).load(img_url).into(imageView);
```